# Count items in array by using ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-filters

I have a JSONfile like this:

```
vm.names = [{
  'name': 'A'
}, {
  'name': 'A'
}, {
  'name': 'B'
}, {
  'name': 'C'
}, {
  'name': 'C'
}]
```

I using AngularJS filter repeat it in HTML:

```
<ul ng-repeat ="name in vm.names | unique'name'>
<li>{{name.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here is issue

A

B

C

So I want count item, I want display like this

A num:2

B num:1

C num:2

How can I do that?

Comment: You want to count them with what purpose? I mean, suppose you have a way to do it, what do you need the number for .... in your html, would you bind it to   any element or something like that?

Comment: I want count item in store :)

Comment: thank you , it work perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `groupBy` filter provided by [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) like in this [runnable fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ns5fv0qh/3/):

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="item in names | groupBy: 'name' ">
      <li>{{item[0].name}}: {{ item.length}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = [{
    'name': 'A'
  }, {
    'name': 'A'
  }, {
    'name': 'B'
  }, {
    'name': 'C'
  }, {
    'name': 'C'
  }];
});
```